# Socket.BeginRecieve is never re-called in the callback function

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, callback

I'm pretty fresh in the game of C# and .NET so I found some exercises on the net. More specifically an asynchronous web server. I'm currently having some problems with getting the callbacks to fire. `Socket.BeginReceive` fires its callback the first time, but when I try to do it recursively (like shown on MSDN Tutorial - to get any remaining data) it never fires. I'm currently using .NET 4.0 and VS2010.

Here is my code:

**HTTPServer.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections;

namespace UPnPServer.net.HTTPServer
{
    public class HTTPServer
    {
        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenerThread;
        private ManualResetEvent allDone;
        private Boolean kill = false;
        private ArrayList requestHandlers;

        public HTTPServer(int port)
        {
            this.allDone = new ManualResetEvent(true);
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
            this.listenerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
            this.requestHandlers = new ArrayList();
            this.listenerThread.Start();
        }

        private void Listen()
        {
            this.tcpListener.Start();
            while (!this.kill)
            {
                this.allDone.Reset();
                tcpListener.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), null);
                this.allDone.WaitOne();
            }
            this.tcpListener.Stop();
        }

        private void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket client = tcpListener.EndAcceptSocket(ar);

            HTTPRequestHandler handler = new HTTPRequestHandler(client);
            handler.RequestProcessed += new HTTPRequestEventHandler(RequestProcessed);
            this.requestHandlers.Add(handler);
            this.allDone.Set();
        }

        private void RequestProcessed(HTTPRequestHandler sender)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Ferdig.");
            this.requestHandlers.Remove(sender);
        }
    }
}
```

**HTTPRequestHandler.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace UPnPServer.net.HTTPServer
{
    public delegate void HTTPRequestEventHandler(HTTPRequestHandler sender);

    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket Socket = null;
        public const int BufferSize = 4096;
        public byte[] Buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
        public StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public class HTTPRequestHandler
    {
        public event HTTPRequestEventHandler RequestProcessed;

        private Socket socket = null;
        private const int bufferSize = 1024;
        private byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        private void OnRequestProcessed()
        {
            if (this.RequestProcessed != null)
            {
                this.RequestProcessed(this);
            }
        }

        public HTTPRequestHandler(Socket client)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Accepted...");
            this.socket = client;
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.Socket = client;
            this.socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }

        private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Hmm...");
            int read = 0;
            read = this.socket.EndReceive(ar);

            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(read);

            if (read > 0)
            {
                this.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(this.buffer, 0, read));
                this.socket.BeginReceive(state.Buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    String request = this.sb.ToString();
                    this.ProcessRequest(request);
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(String request)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(request);
            this.socket.Close();
            this.OnRequestProcessed();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me out here, as I am about to go insane. Thanks.

Comment: For one thing, you've got two different buffers; you're reading into one and out of another.

Comment: Are you sending additional requests?  The callback only fires when data is received.  As an aside, the design looks poor to me.  The data processing will only occur on a zero-length data read from the socket.  With asynchronous sockets, this usually occurs when the socket is closed.  In other words, as designed, it look like the request will only be processed once the socket is closed somehow.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for answering. The two different buffers are only a glitch, sorry. I was under the impression that the callback is fired when ANY data is recieved (not necessarily complete messages). I just want to process one request only. You are totally right Matt - as of now the processing is only commenced once the connection is closed. The design is the same as in the MSDN tutorial I read. What would be a better design?